# In php we can access static member functions using class objects. Can someone please tell any practicle use of this feature

Tags: static, php-5.3

In php we can call static member functions using class objects. For example

```
class Human
{
    public static function Speak()
    {
        echo "I am a human.";
    }
}

$human = new Human();
$human->Speak();
```

What we would expect is that a static member function can only be called using the class name and not the class instance variable (object). But what i have seen while programming is that php allows calling a static member function using the class object also. Is there any practical use or some important reason that this feature has been provided in php ?

This feature exists in java and c++ also. Thanks Oli for pointing this out in your response.

Comment: Probably to mimic Java. Though, I don't know what purpose it serves there either.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as in other OO languages, such as C++ and Java.  Why would you want the interpreter to *prevent* this?

**UPDATE**

My best guess for this (and this is *only* a guess) is "for convenience".  In essence, why should the user of your class necessarily care whether a given member function is static or not? In some circumstances, this will certainly matter; in others, maybe not.  I'm not saying this is a great justification, but it's all I can come up with!

Comment: I basically come from .net background, where i use c# for my programming projects. This thing is not allowed in c#. I am curious to know that is there any special reason for this feature. Because as per theory statics have nothing to do with instance variables. They are class level things.

Comment: Why _not_ wanting something doesn't sound like a great justification for it being.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out that c++ and java also provide this feature. i forgot to add it to my question. I tried this with java also and knew that java provides this feature.

Comment: @zneak: Well, given that pre-existing languages already offer this "functionality", it would be a curious design decision to prohibit it in PHP.

Comment: Following this trail of thought, PHP should implement everything other languages implement, just because they do.

Comment: @oli: I agree with you on the point that pre-existing languages already offer this functionality, so they continued it in php too. But can you please offer some help, from your experience, on providing some practical use of this feature. This would then help me understand why this feature exists in these languages.

Comment: @zneak: OO was a bolt-on addition to PHP.  To attract developers, it would make sense to mimic the abilities of other languages relatively closely.  I'm not saying this is *definitely* the reason, but it's certainly a reasonable possibility.

Comment: @Ravinder: The best answer I can think of is "for convenience".  In essence, why should the user of your class necessarily care whether a given member function is static or not?  In some circumstances, this will certainly matter; in others, maybe not.  I'm not saying this is a great justification, but it's all I can come up with!

Comment: @Oli: I agree with you on this. I would like to vote this thought too. Can you please post this as an answer to this question so that i can vote. This is one of the possible reasons for this feature in php and other languages.

Answer (score 1):

it allows you to abstract from the particular definition of the method, so that for example if you had to turn it into a static one at some point, you don't have to rewrite all the method calls!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for PHP, (or really for anything) but consider this hypothetical C++:

```
class base{
public:
    static void speak(){cout<<"base\n";}
};

class sub :public base {
public: 
    static void speak(){cout<<"sub\n"; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    base *base1 = new base();
    base1->speak();

    sub *sub1 = new sub();
    sub1->speak();

    base *sub2 = new sub();
    sub2->speak();
    ((sub*)sub2)->speak();
}
```

The output would be:

```
base
sub
base
sub
```

I'm sure it could be useful... maybe helping you determine which class's static method you should call based on the object currently in hand.